# How to use python to detect if an application is running and if a message box is displayed under MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit test for an application on Mac OS using python. There is one problem I encounter and have no idea how to do it. I want the testing program to check if the application is running by checking process and I also want to check if a message box is displayed. In addition, I hope testing program can automatically click button on message box. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it with AppleScript:

```
import subprocess

def is_runnning(app):
    count = int(subprocess.check_output(["osascript",
                "-e", "tell application \"System Events\"",
                "-e", "count (every process whose name is \"" + app + "\")",
                "-e", "end tell"]).strip())
    return count > 0

print is_runnning("iTunes")
```

See also [this](http://daringfireball.net/2006/10/how_to_tell_if_an_app_is_running) for some variations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) for inspecting various parts of the host system. With this python library you can inspect which processes are running.

As far as interacting with OS X itself, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281133/controlling-the-mouse-from-python-in-os-x) has some nice information about controlling the mouse and keyboard using [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. After digging some time, I found using apple script in Python is easiest approach.