# Python3 - Detect mouse click on screen - Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos

How do I detect a mouse click on screen on a mac?

I have seen many people use win32api however this is only supported for windows, and not for mac also.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question with answers:

- [How to control the mouse in Mac using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281133/how-to-control-the-mouse-in-mac-using-python)

By using the ctypes module:

- [Controlling mouse with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna click on the screen with python i recommend you use pyautogui. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ If you want to download it onto terminal just type pip install pyautogui!

Here are some clicks you can use:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click()          # Click the mouse.

pyautogui.click(100, 200)  # Move the mouse to XY coordinates and click it.

pyautogui.click('button.png') # Find where button.png appears on the screen and click it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers were about "controlling" the mouse instead of "monitoring" the mouse.

To monitor mouse activities like clicking, you may refer to
[pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)